# Ignore falsey values when binding an array to an object property in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am using Angular 1.4.8 and would like to put **only the checked values** of a list into an array. This array then needs to be the value of an object property, like this:

```
myObject = {
  "myArray": [
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "pear"
  ]
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <form name="myForm">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in vm.fruits track by $index">
           <label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myObject.myArray[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{fruit}}'" ng-false-value="undefined" />{{fruit}}
           </label>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    <pre>myObject = {{vm.myObject | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myObject = {
    myArray: []
  }
  vm.fruits = ["apple", "orange", "pear", "naartjie"];
});
```

For easy reference, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/rw6ypf4k/1/).

Note that when you check and then uncheck a list item, the array retains a value of `null`. I do not want `null` bound to the array because it adds to its length and this is causing issues with other code.

How can I ignore binding falsey values like `null`, `undefined`, etc...?

Comment: Based on the way you have your bindings, you are explicitly setting the values of specific indexes with the true/false value bindings. You would either need to adjust the behavior of your html to execute some JS to perform the upkeep of myArray, or adjust your other code to accomodate the null values to get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to add/remove the fruits from array.

Something like this:

```
vm.insertIntoArray = function(value){
    var index = vm.fruitsArray.indexOf(value);
    if(index === -1){
        vm.fruitsArray.push(value);
    }else{
        vm.fruitsArray.splice(index,1);
    }
}
```

Also, set ng-change attribute into your checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myObject.myArray[$index]" ng-change="vm.insertIntoArray(fruit)" ng-value="'{{fruit}}'"/>
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fwu045u0/

Comment: This solution works with a minor tweak. You put the value into splice instead of the index. This fiddle based on yours works. https://jsfiddle.net/fwu045u0/

Comment: Yeah, sure. I was useing the value instead of the index by mistake. Thanks @RayfenWindspear.

Comment: Victor Hugo, great solution. It's just slightly different that what I was looking for (your code pushes to an array but I need that array to be the property of an object). Nonetheless, thank you very much. Seeing how you approach this problem is extremely helpful. @RayfenWindspear, thank you for the edit, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements [I have implemented](https://jsfiddle.net/np6an45b/) something along the lines of what you may want:

```
vm.boxChecked = function(item){

   var index = vm.myObject.myArray.indexOf(item);    
   if(index !== -1)
       vm.myObject.myArray.splice(index, 1);
   else
    vm.myObject.myArray.push(item);
};
```

The fiddle also will check any checkbox whose value appears in the myArray on load. You will see it auto checks 'apple' for you as I have put it in the array. IF you wish to remove this functionality, simply remove apple from the array and the `ng-checked` portion of the directive and the behavior should be as you desire.

Comment: I removed this as the best answer because after looking at it more closely, you removed `ng-model` from my fiddle but I need `ng-model` in my solution. According to the angular docs, `ng-model` cannot be used with `ng-checked`. If you know of a workaround, please post.

Comment: Unfortunately your data structure doesn't support all your requirements. You will have to make some changes to your objects if you wish to use ng-model. If you are tracking by $index in your post: `ng-model="vm.myObject.myArray[$index]"` you are bound to set an element at some point that is in the in the middle of your fruit collection. If you set $index = 2 for example, there has to be something occupying $index[0-1]. Since I can't see the code that is affected by adding `null` values to the array, it is hard to fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dLO0bDOBb6F3W9mlePA?p=preview) for the same problem.

You can modify your model to track the selected items by adding some `selected` property to the original objects, e.g.

```
<li ng-repeat="fruit in vm.fruits track by $index">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.selected" ng-true-value="'{{fruit}}'" ng-false-value="undefined" />{{fruit}}
   </label>
</li>
```

Then you have several solutions to build the array of selected elements:

- with a function that filter the `fruit` array on `selected==true` property
- with a watch on the `fruits` collection that will update the selected array when an item is selected/unselected.
- by adding `ng-change="toggleSelect(fruit)" in the input and managing a separate list of selected items

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes down to tracking by `$index`. Removing `$index` from this code:

```
    <li ng-repeat="fruit in vm.fruits track by $index">
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myObject.myArray[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{fruit}}'" ng-false-value="undefined" />{{fruit}}
       </label>
     </li>
```

and replacing it with `(key, value)` like this:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.fruits track by value">
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.myObject.myArray.value[key]" ng-change="vm.insertIntoArray(value)" ng-true-value="'{{value}}'" />{{value}}
       </label>
     </li>
```

solved my issue.

Although other answers to-date were helpful and contributed to the final solution, none included everything that I needed. See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/q6ctLv2a/) for more details.